# How to make a responsive background grid of user's profile pics?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I want to create a background with a grid of images from my user's profile pictures.

I've tried to make something like Adobe Spark Site (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeKwn.jpg) but failed, since the Adobe Site background is a static image.

My application is created using Ruby on Rails, however my question is in regards to HTML, and how to make a dynamic grid so that when I resize the window, it responsively resizes the images as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried float or flexbox?

Comment: @jedifans flexbox looks interesting but is there a way that when there is no space left for the images, instead of going to to next row, they disappear or turn not visible?

Comment: @AntónioPinheiro `flex-wrap: no-wrap;` You should read up on [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) guide. It's great.

Comment: I think so, see [flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap), and I guess combine with `overflow:hidden` on the container. Just bear in mind that IE8 doesn't support flexbox, if you need to target IE8.

Comment: @CalebAnthony Thanks i will try it

Comment: @jedifans Thanks i will try it